# appengine: parse a csv data in uploaded file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

Are there any modules or packages which help parsing csv content from a uploaded csv file in appengine. tried using the csv package in python. but it could parse only files in file system but could not data..
http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it could parse only files in file
>   system but could not data

No, [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) accepts any object that supports line-by-line iteration. Assuming cgi.FieldStorage supports it, and assuming you've posted a file named "file", you should be able to do this:

```
import csv
for row in csv.reader(self.request.POST['file']):
  # process row
```

Comment: Or, pull the blob back out of the blogstore and pass it to csv.reader(). That might be something you want to do in a backend to avoid having processing blow the 30 second request limit.

Comment: `code`import csv 
`code`for row in csv.DictReader(open('contacts.csv', 'rU'))
`code` self.response.out.write(row)


this is working fine when tested 
`code`for row in csv.DictReader(self.request.POST.get('CSV').file.read())
`code` self.response.out.write(row)
 

when the contacts.csv same file is suplied via webbrowser it is not able to prase the contents of it

Answer (score 0):

There is a blobstore input format for the App Engine Mapper: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

It will read each line from the CSV and send it to your mapper for reading/import. Be careful though because it breaks if there are escaped new lines in the CSV.

Here is an example with the Java implementation: http://ikaisays.com/2010/08/11/using-the-app-engine-mapper-for-bulk-data-import/